# File Upload with ExtJS onFilefieldChange

Tags: extjs, file-upload

I have a file upload field which is part of a larger form. When a file is selected, the file should be uploaded to an API as post(?) data.

So I started with

```
onFilefieldChange: function(filefield, value, e0pts) {
    filefield.form.submit({
        url: '../api/FileUpload?type=logo',
        waitMsg: 'Uploading your logo...',
        success: function(fp, o) {
            msg('Success', 'Processed file "' + o.result.file + '" on the server');
        }
    });
}
```

But wouldn't this submit the whole form, not just the file!?

With me, it does neither. Instead, I get the error message *"Cannot call submit of undefined"*, but shouldn't ExtJS fill the filefield variable for me?

Last thing, can I submit the file as simple post data, or is it always "multipart form data"?

Comment: What do you mean "simple post data". If you're uploading a file, how else are you going to read it?

Comment: When I get JSON, I just take the POST data blob and put it into the JSON Deserializer. With multipart form data, I have to extract the correct chunk first.

Comment: That's how files get uploaded. How are you going to encode a binary file in JSON?

Comment: Why would I encode a file in JSON? The POST data has MIME application/json, but when I upload a jpeg, it could have been image/jpeg as well... not necessarily application/multipart-form-data. But I got it, no such thing available, I'll have to work with what I got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think from your code that you need to go `up` to the parent form from the field and submit and then it should be defined.

`filefield.up('form').getForm().submit()`